# Взаимодействие между классами с использованием вызова функции через переменную

Tags: php

Никак не найду причину в документации почему этот код отлично работает в 7.0.5:

```
<?php
class A {
    private static $a;

    function __construct() {
        self::$a = new B;
        echo "1. ".__CLASS__.' '.self::$a->b."\n";

        self::$a->b = 'A::test'; //7.0.5 ok
        echo "2. ".__CLASS__.' '.self::$a->b."\n";

        echo self::$a; // ok expected
    }

    public static function test() {
        return 'ok';
    }
}

class B {
    public $b;

    public function __toString() {
        echo "3. ".__CLASS__.' '.$this->b."\n";

        $tmp = $this->b;
        echo "4. ".__CLASS__.' '.$tmp.' '.is_string($this->b).' '.is_callable($this->b)."\n";

        $res = $tmp();
        echo "5. ".__CLASS__.' '.$res."\n";

        return $res;
    }
}

$a = new A;
```

Результат:

```
1. A 
2. A A::test
3. B A::test
4. B A::test 1 1
5. B ok
ok
```

И выдает ошибку для 5.6.2 "Call to undefined function A::test()" на строке $res = $tmp()?

Результат:

```
1. A 
2. A A::test
3. B A::test
4. B A::test 1 1
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function A::test()
```

Если использовать call_user_func вместо $res = $tmp() - все работает, но очень хочется обратиться к функции через переменную. Возможно? Прошу помощи и знаний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если мне не изменяет память, то до 7-й версии вместо

```
self::$a->b = 'A::test'; //7.0.5 ok
```

надо

```
self::$a->b = array('A', 'test'); //5.6 should work I guess...
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы, так будет работать. Странно, что прямой вызов A::test() и  call_user_func нормально работают, а вызов через переменную - нет. Похоже, что это особенность реализации. В документации наткнулся в примере:  $func = "Foo::bar";
$func();    // выведет "bar" в PHP 7.0.0 и выше; в предыдущих версиях это приведет к фатальной ошибке

Comment: Подождем, может существует какой-нибудь трюк обойти это ограничение.

Comment: а я вот ка-кто не понял, зачем вам именно "A::test"? Что мешает разрабатывать с учетом ограничения?

Comment: ... тем более, что array('A', 'test') в 7-й версии также работает, а значит может использоваться как кросс-версионный подход (хотя, признаюсь, не проверял, но процентов на 90 уверен).

Comment: Никто не мешает разрабатывать с учетом ограничения. Понятно, что можно сделать преобразование. В задаче был важен строковый тип. Преобразования не слишком желательны, но, естественно, при отсутствии возможности, будут использованы.

Comment: В инете вариантов не нашел. Скорее всего - желаемого решения нет. Вопрос закрываю. @AlexandrX, спасибо за участие!